# How do you handle splicing a variable that is shared among async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm worried about a splice in one of my async functions causing another function to throw an error in a situation like this:

```
var sharedObject = [{key: 'foo', value: {varA: 1, varB: 5}}]

readObject: function(key) { 
    var index = findIndex(sharedObject, key)            <- line 4
    var b = sharedObject[index].value.varB              <- line 5
}

spliceObject: function(key) {
    var index = findIndex(sharedObject, key)
    sharedObject.splice(index,1)                        <- line 10
}
```

If the readObject and spliceObject functions are called asynchronously, and line 10 executes right in between line 4 and line 5, will line 5 throw an error because that entry in the object doesn't exist anymore?

Or am I missing something with how async functions execute?

Comment: What you describe can't happen, a function will run from start to finish, and no other code will run in the meantime. The async callback will have to wait until the call stack is cleared.

Comment: Not to mention that `splice()` and `findIndex()` are for arrays and you don't have an array

Comment: Before accessing the object from the array using `index`, you'll have to check if `index` is valid (i.e. it is not equal to `-1` which means no object was found).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're worried about is (thankfully) impossible due to Javascript's single-threaded nature. Asynchronous code - including async functions and `setTimeout`s, will only run once the stack is clear. So, an ongoing thread will not be interrupted by something else asynchronous - the current thread must terminate before the next one starts.

Comment: Does this no longer apply when node is scaled to multiple instances? I'm guessing in that case you just need to design your app to have the instances be independent of each other?

Comment: @jomak73 - Multiple instances live in their own processes and each have their own set of variables so one instance can't even see or modify the variables of another instance.  If you want to share data between instances, it is common to use some sort of database (like redis) for the shared data which generally has concurrency features which you need to use properly.